# How to color the region between three mutually tangent circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to  color the region between three mutually tangent circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\draw[ultra thick](0,0) circle [radius=2];
\draw[ultra thick] (4,0) circle [radius=2];
\draw[ultra thick] (2,-3.46) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe with `\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}` or `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` from `pgfplots` package. You can read pgfplots 2015 manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do it with arcs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\fill[red] (2,0) arc[radius=2,start angle=-180,end angle=-120]
 arc[radius=2,start angle=60,end angle=120]
 arc[radius=2,start angle=-60,end angle=0] (2,0);
\draw[ultra thick](0,0) circle [radius=2];
\draw[ultra thick] (4,0) circle [radius=2];
\draw[ultra thick] (2,-3.46) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: filled arcs]

Answer (score 9):

A simple approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\fill[red!80!black]
  (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (2,{-2*sqrt(3)}) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thick,fill=white]
  (0,0) circle [radius=2] 
  (4,0) circle [radius=2]
  (2,{-2*sqrt(3)}) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

1. You can use a single `\draw` for the three circles.
2. Instead of manual calculations (`-3.46`), you can let TikZ do the calculations for you: `-2*sqrt(3)`.
3. The idea is to fill a triangle with vertices in the centers of the circles and then fill/draw the circles.